# How to bind ListView after jquery call in Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0, data-binding, static

I want bind new data to my ListView. But I can't

In server side I have:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void ChangeConditions(string ConditionIs)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = GetNewData(ConditionIs);

        //can't to do it, because my WebMethod is static.
        //listView.DataSource = dt;
        //listView.DataBind();
    }

    private static DataTable GetNewData(string conditions)
    {
        DataTable NewData = new DataTable();

        //Get new data from DB and want to return DataTable with new data.
        //...
        return NewData;
    }
```

In client side I have:

> $('#btnSend').live('click', function () {
>
> ```
> $.ajax({
>     type: "POST",
>     url: "default.aspx/ChangeConditions",
>     data: '{"ConditionIs":"' + condition + '"}',
>     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>     dataType: "json",
>     success: function (msg) {
>
>     }
> }); });
> ```

How I can rebind data to ListView?

P.S. When I write this post, I researched my question. And found solution:

- put UpdatePanel around my ListView;
- put ScriptManager above UpdatePanel;
- put this line inside success function in JS: __doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', '');

And when I send my data from client to server into [WebMethod], I can fill my static DataTable, and Bind it in Page_Load.
But I want to interesting, can I use some other solution? Or maybe in my solution can have some bugs?

Comment: You need to return the data from the WebMethod.  Right now, it's a void.  Make it DataTable.

Comment: Ok, but how I'll bind DataTable to ListView in JS?

Comment: I will get back with you on this soon with a working code sample.

Comment: @TheGeekYouNeed is it soon yet?